# Resource not found anymore after install

Tags: android, eclipse

I've updated to the latest **SDK (21 and 21.0.1)** via Android SDK Manager.
Now if I compile and upload it to the emulator the app crashes.

I see **no app icon** in the **drawer** and once the app want to acces any recourses it crashes with "**Resources not found Exception**".

In Eclipse I **don't see any error** and the **R.java** is also there.
I've tried several times to clean up the project and other stuff, but no success.

The strange thing is that after install the app looses all resources it seems.
Because the app **don't shows the icon** and *no name* in the drawer.
Instead of the name I see the **main package name**.

I've tried it in the Emulator with 4.4.2 or 4.3 or 5.0 always the same.

**Update:**
If I try to "**Export unsigned Application Package**" in "Android Tools" I get following error
**Failed to export application - Command-line-Error -1073741819** and no exported application.
There is something weird going on here :-(

**Exception trace:**
Command-line Error -1073741819
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeAapt(BuildHelper.java:977)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.packageResources(BuildHelper.java:288)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:167)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper$2.run(ExportHelper.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)